# Using flexpaper to retrieve to display swf file from database.

Tags: php, flash, flexpaper

**swf file has store inside database and need to display using flexpaper.**

**This is code for flexpaper display file.**

```
$('#documentViewer').FlexPaperViewer(
    { config : {

    SWFFile : '<?php echo "present_retrieve.php?id=".$id.""; ?>',

    Scale : 0.6,
    ZoomTransition : 'easeOut',
    ZoomTime : 0.5,
    ZoomInterval : 0.2,
    FitPageOnLoad : true,
    FitWidthOnLoad : false,
    FullScreenAsMaxWindow : false,
    ProgressiveLoading : false,
    MinZoomSize : 0.2,
    MaxZoomSize : 5,
    SearchMatchAll : false,
    InitViewMode : 'Portrait',
    RenderingOrder : 'flash',
    StartAtPage : '',

    ViewModeToolsVisible : true,
    ZoomToolsVisible : true,
    NavToolsVisible : true,
    CursorToolsVisible : true,
    SearchToolsVisible : true,
    WMode : 'window',
    localeChain: 'en_US' }}
```

**present_retrieve.php**

```
<?php

// Connect to the database
        $host="localhost"; // Host name 
        $username="root"; // Mysql username 
        $password=""; // Mysql password 
        $db_name="is"; // Database name 
        $tbl_name="presentation"; // Table name 

        $conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password"); 
        if(! $conn )
        {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($db_name);

    if (isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty($_GET["id"])) { 

            $id= $_GET['id'];

            $query = "SELECT file_name, file_type, file_size, content FROM $tbl_name WHERE file_id = '$id'";

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

                    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    $name=$row1['file_name'];
                    $type=$row1['file_type'];
                    $size = $row1['file_size'];
                    $content = $row1['content'];

            header("Content-length: $size");
            header("Content-type: $type");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
            echo $content;

            mysql_close($conn);
            exit;
            }


?>
```

**However, the file doesn't show in the flexpaper**.

Please help me to figure out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have an extra space somewhere in your output and that this is corrupting the swf file. Check for any leading or trailing spaces in your php script (outside the php script tags).

You also don't need the content-disposition header in your response. I would recommend the following headers for swf files:

header('Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

Comment: i have change my header as u recommended... yet i still faced the same problem ... is there any other solution ? thanks a lot ...

Comment: How are you converting your swf files? Maybe its not the response but the swf file that is incorrect. Have a look at the following page for the parameters we recommend:

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/Convert-PDF-documents-to-web-manually.jsp

Comment: i used swftool convert it then upload to database... then only retrieve the swf file from database to display using flexpaper